# Can I rely on the 701 permissions to prevent users within the same group from messing with each other's data?

Tags: linux, security, permissions, file-permissions

Some time ago I've learned that assigning all users to the same group and setting 701 to their home directories prevents them from messing with each other's data, yet lets a system program, such as a web-server, to access the data.

So I create a group `users` then two users, `alice:users` and `bob:users` with `/opt/www/alice` and `/opt/www/bob` home directories respectively. Then, after logging under `alice` I am unable to enter `/opt/www/bob` and vice versa.

So it seems to me that permissions aren't always checked for the every type (user, group, everyone) but rather gradually, essentially stopping after a negative match. I.e, in my case

- when a user from the same group tries to open the directory:

  - first, we are checking a user, it is not the same but `7` let us go further
  - then `0` stops us from accessing the the directory *and also stops the further permissions checking*
  - so we don't fall into x-for-everyone case from `1`
- while for a user from the the different group:

  - first, we are checking a user, it is not the same but `7` let us go further
  - then we are checking for a group, it is `0` but the group is different, so it let's us pass
  - so we're able to open the directory thanks to `1` being "everyone" to this directory

Is this conjecture correct? Can I rely on this behavior? What are possible downsides from this setup?

Comment: Seems like you’re missing some information between “So I create users…” and “So it seems to me…” the former makes sense, the latter makes no sense based on the former.

Comment: @Appleoddity I apologize for the confusion, but isn't "after logging under alice I am unable to enter /opt/www/bob" being that missing link? Like "So I create users, then login under one and then, *being unable to enter each other's directory*, I suppose so and so..."?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got it slightly wrong, but the outcome is the same. `701` means that:

- the user marked as owner gets full permissions, `7`
- a user in the group marked as the group owner gets no permissions, `0`
- everyone gets execute permissions, `1`

So if the owner & permissions on `/opt/www/bob` are `bob:users` and `701` respectively, then `bob` gets full permissions and everyone can 'execute' the directory. This means anyone would be able to access their own files or group owned files within the folder, but they can't list the contents.

Example:

```
$> mkdir test
$> echo 'foo' > test/foo.txt
$> chmod 100 test/
$> ls -l test/
Permission denied
$> cat test/foo.txt
foo
$>
```

So yes, other users in the group would have no permissions, but everyone has execute permissions. You'd be better to set the permissions to `740` if you want to allow the group to read and no one else. Or `741` to achieve what you have, but be a bit clearer?

Comment: The thing is, **I don't** want  to allow the group to read

Comment: Why not just set the ownership to `bob:bob` then?

Comment: because at the time I didn't know how to let a web server read the files with such permisions

Comment: @shearn89 In Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 and Debian 10, `chmod 701 test/`, `sudo chown root test/`, `cat test/foo.txt` prints `cat: test/foo.txt: Permission denied`, `sudo chown root:www-data test/`, `cat test/foo.txt` prints `foo`. I don't have other Linux to test in.